# How do I pass a parameter value from one stored procedure to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm trying to pass the input parameters from one stored procedure to another stored procedure, the value of the parameter will be used to be inserted into a table.

I have two stored procedures, here is the logic for the SP's:

First one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [abc].[SP1](
@ID1     INT
@ID2     INT
@Date    VARCHAR(10)
@Value   VARCHAR(50)
)

AS 

Select into #temp...

EXEC [abc].[SP2] @ID1, @ID2, @Date, @Value

Select...
```

Second one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [abc].[sp2](
@bID1    INT
@bID2    INT
@bDate   VARCHAR(10)
@Value   VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @bID1 INT, @bID2 INT, @bDate VARCHAR(10), @Value VARCHAR(50)


--main part that I'm concerned with, getting the parameter values to work
SELECT @bID1, @bID2, @bDate, @Value, x.col1, x.col2 
INTO [abc].[tableA]
FROM tableX x
```

When I try this I receive an error saying that I, "must declare the scalar variable"

Answer (score 1):

It's not how you create procedures in SQL Server. You should do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP1]
 @ID1     INT
,@ID2     INT
,@Date    VARCHAR(10)
,@Value   VARCHAR(50)

AS 

Select into #temp...
```

Secondly, when you declared parameteres for the procedure you cannot declare variables with the same names below:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [abc].[sp2]
 @bID1    INT
,@bID2    INT
,@bDate   VARCHAR(10)
,@Value   VARCHAR(50)

AS

--main part that I'm concerned with, getting the parameter values to work
SELECT @bID1, @bID2, @bDate, @Value, x.col1, x.col2 
INTO [abc].[tableA]
FROM tableX x
```